# Example program from Automate the Boring Stuff not working as described

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I've been poking about the internet and not seeing this anywhere so it must be something I've done but I'm not sure what.

The book Automate the Boring Stuff with Python uses the following code to explain Dictionaries:

```
    birthdays = {'Alice': 'Apr 1', 'Bob': 'Dec 12', 'Carol': 'Mar 4'}
    while True:
            print('Enter a name: (blank to quit)')
            name = input()
            if name == '':
                    break

    if name in birthdays:
            print(birthdays[name] + ' is the birthday of ' + name)
    else:
            print('I do not have birthday information for ' + name)
            print('What is their birthday?')
            bday = input()
            birthdays[name] = bday
            print('Birthday database updated.')
```

This code doesn't generate any errors for me, but when I ran it, it did not return anything when I tried to enter one of the names in the dict. If I entered nothing, the program reacted with "I do not have birthday information for  What is their birthday?"

I tried tweaking the code in the following way:

```
birthdays = {'Alice': 'Apr 1', 'Bob': 'Dec 12', 'Carol': 'Mar 4'}

while True:
    print('Enter a name: (blank to quit)')
    name = input()
    if name == '':
        break

    if name in birthdays:
        print(birthdays[name] + ' is the birthday of ' + name)
    else:
        print('I do not have birthday information for ' + name)
        print('What is their birthday?')
        bday = input()
        birthdays[name] = bday
        print('Birthday database updated.')
```

Now I am able to enter an existing name and get the correct result, but if I enter a name not in the dictionary, it returns nothing and again tells me to enter a name.

Obviously this is just an example and I get what it's supposed to do, but why is it doing this?

Comment: Your code ran fine for me, is the indentation the same in your latter example as to what you are trying to run? That was the problem originally.

Comment: Hmmm, good question. I had retyped this especially for the post, so it's possible that the indentation was not the same. Or that it was. What I should have done is made another git branch when I started trying to tweak it but of course that didn't occur to me until it was way too late. Mea culpa.

Answer (score 0):

```
birthdays[name] = bday
```

This line is the problem after your second code block. You have to update values in the dictionary with new ones. In your example  you assign the `bday` to a name that should already be in dictionary.

EDIT:

```
birthdays = {'Alice': 'Apr 1', 'Bob': 'Dec 12', 'Carol': 'Mar 4'}

while True:
    print('Enter a name: (blank to quit)')
    name = input()
    if name == '':
        break

    if name in birthdays:
        print(name + ' birthday is ' + birthdays[name])
    else:
        print('I do not have birthday information for ' + name)
        print('What is their birthday?(ex: Apr 4): ')
        bday = input()
        birthdays.update({name: bday})
        print('Birthday database updated.')
        print(birthdays)
```

Comment: Okay, that's fair. But I'm still confused as to why the original code, which is an example from the book, did not work correctly. I'm concerned that there may be something incorrect about my environment.

Answer (score 0):

My money is on the else block for the if/else not being indented the same as the if. This is the only way I was able to reproduce the behavior you are describing:

```py
birthdays = {'Alice': 'Apr 1', 'Bob': 'Dec 12', 'Carol': 'Mar 4'}

while True:
    print('Enter a name: (blank to quit)')
    name = input()
    if name == '':
        break

    if name in birthdays:
        print(birthdays[name] + ' is the birthday of ' + name)
# Notice the else corresponds to "while", not the above "if".
else:
    print('I do not have birthday information for ' + name)
    print('What is their birthday?')
    bday = input()
    birthdays[name] = bday
    print('Birthday database updated.')
```

Note that this is in fact valid Python and the `else` clause will be entered if the `while` exits without a `break` statement.

For example:

```py
while 1 != 1:
    pass
else:
    print("Got to else.")
```

Output:

```
Got to else.
```